# how to find DNS in java which gives A, NAPTR and other records along with TTL and port (newbie)

Tags: java, dns, port, ttl

I do not want to use dnsjava or other third party library. Is there any way that enables to find the TTL and port values for A or NAPTR or any other records? may be using java.net package? Using getallbyName, I can get ip address but what if I want TTL and port as well.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: port as in IP port - such as 80 for HTTP?  I didn't think DNS held this information.

Comment: yes port as in IP port. Than how shall I find port?

Comment: The port depends on the service you are trying to access.

Answer (score 0):

**1.** Try doing a `Ping` using the `Runtime().getRuntime().exec()`, then extract the `TTL` (Time to Live) value from it..

**2.** It **worked** in `Windows`, i am **not sure** how to use it in `Linux`.

Comment: I want to do this in a java or android.

Comment: @user1633260 If you are on `Windows PC`, use this in your java program to get the TTL value.